# how to Update same member_id if Phone number and Country code exist in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
 public class RegistrationController : ApiController
    {
        public DefaultRespons GetRegister(int os_id, string device_id, int country_code, long mobile_no)
        {
            LociDataClassesDataContext dc = new LociDataClassesDataContext();
            registration reg = new registration();
            reg.os_id = os_id;
            reg.device_id = device_id;
            reg.country_code = country_code;
            reg.mobile_number = mobile_no;
            reg.verification_code = new Random().Next(1000, 9999);
            dc.registrations.InsertOnSubmit(reg);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            Twilio.TwilioRestClient client = new Twilio.TwilioRestClient("ACcount", "token");
            Twilio.SMSMessage message = client.SendSmsMessage("+16782493911", "+" + reg.country_code + "" + reg.mobile_number, "Your verification code for Locii is: " + reg.verification_code);
            if (message.RestException != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(message.RestException.Message);
            return new DefaultRespons(1, "OK",Registration.getResponse(reg));
        }

        public DefaultRespons GetActivate(int registration_id, int verification_code)
        {
            LociDataClassesDataContext dc = new LociDataClassesDataContext();
            registration reg = dc.registrations.Where(r => r.id == registration_id && r.verification_code == verification_code && r.registration_date==null).SingleOrDefault();




            if (reg!=null)
            {
                List<registration> previous = dc.registrations.Where(r => r.mobile_number == reg.mobile_number && r.country_code == reg.country_code).ToList();
                foreach (registration r in previous)
                {
                    member mem = dc.members.Where(mb => mb.registration_id == r.id).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (mem!=null)
                        mem.online_status = -1;
                }
                member m = new member();
                m.registration_id = reg.id;
                m.online_status = 0;
                reg.registration_date = DateTime.Now;
                dc.members.InsertOnSubmit(m);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
                return new DefaultRespons(1, "Activated", Activation.getResponse(m));
            }
            else
            {
                return new DefaultRespons(1, "Failed", "");
            }
        }
```

Here is My code from which i am creating new Member_id  . when i Enter following parameter and i activate from code then in response there is new Member_id  id creating and it return . now i want when i register with same Phone number and country code whose Member id  is already create i want to return same member_id it should not update new Member id please help me how to check the Phone number and country code already exist in database and return same member id. please help me i am not able to do this how to check .

Comment: @har07 u there please look this issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi Anil try this sample code:
make required changes as per your code

```
public int CheckUser(int countrycode, long mobileno)
{
LociDataClassesDataContext dc = new LociDataClassesDataContext();
int id = from b in dc.registrations
         where b.country_code.Equals(countrycode) && b.mobile_number.Equals(mobileno)
         select b.registration_id;
return id;
}

    public DefaultRespons GetRegister(int os_id, string device_id, int country_code, long mobile_no)
    {
        LociDataClassesDataContext dc = new LociDataClassesDataContext();
        int reg_id = CheckUser(country_code, mobile_no);
        if (reg_id == 0)
        {
            registration reg = new registration();
            reg.os_id = os_id;
            reg.device_id = device_id;
            reg.country_code = country_code;
            reg.mobile_number = mobile_no;
            reg.verification_code = new Random().Next(1000, 9999);
            dc.registrations.InsertOnSubmit(reg);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            Twilio.TwilioRestClient client = new Twilio.TwilioRestClient("AC3c23fee017f23f5061a6b5d3be6f74da", "6fe81560f88f3850c5ad5d4a7b8a5f50");
            Twilio.SMSMessage message = client.SendSmsMessage("+16782493911", "+" + reg.country_code + "" + reg.mobile_number, "Your verification code for Locii is: " + reg.verification_code);
            if (message.RestException != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(message.RestException.Message);
            return new DefaultRespons(1, "OK", Registration.getResponse(reg));
        }
        else
        {

            //your code what you want to do with the reg_id
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is issue coming in Model class no default response for generate Member id which is already there please help

Comment: can you explain a bit more @Anil

Comment: in Else condition  how i will get member_id which already in database on wht basis coz we have only One Default response

Comment: reg_id will never be null, its a value type.

Answer (score 0):

@Arijit - For best practice, please make sure to not include your auth token in your code examples, or at least make sure to reset it any time you share it.  Thanks!